# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using Maven

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

So I wanted to try out Guava and instead of going the easy way of manualy importing the library with it's jar file, I decided to use Maven. I added it to my pom.xml file and ran clean&install. Now my code seems to compile as imports work fine inside eclipse, but when I try to run my code, I get Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception. This is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestCommonLibaries</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestCommonLibaries</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

So I googled alot on this, the most common problem seem to be that it's not specified on the classpath, So I looked at it in run configurations and it seems to be there alright. I also found code that Is supposed to add the classpath explicity in the pom.xml and copy the jars to the lib folder, like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestCommonLibaries</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestCommonLibaries</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>




  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
               <mainClass>main/java/main/Main.java</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>



    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

But it gives me the same error.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Code:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> gList = Lists.newArrayList("foo","bar");

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried right click on project->spring tools->update maven dependencies?

Comment: Yes I have. I have also tried the options for clean.

Comment: and you are sure the error is because of guava and not something else?

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to download again your guava lib. May be maven have not correctly downloaded it previously.

To do that, you have to delete your guava 20.0 folder in the .m2 folder (meven local repo).

Go to your .m2 repertory, find guave folder et delete 20.0 folder. The path to this folder seems like that: 
C:\Users{userName}.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0

When this folder is deleted, go to your project and try to make "update maven dependecies". Maven will download again the missings libs.